# Hibernate: long CMT transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, transactions

I have two beans: **FirstBean** and **SecondBean**.

**FirstBean** have method **method1** with REQUIRED transaction attribute, **SecondBean** have method **method2** with NOT_SUPPORTED transaction attribute. 
method1 invokes method2.

```
@Stateless
class FirstBean implement IFirstBean
{
   ISecondBean secondBean;

   @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
   void method1()
   {
      //...
      secondBean.method2()
      //...
   }
}

@Stateless
class SecondBean implement ISecondBean
{
   @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
   void method2()
   {
      //....
   }
}
```

and it works well.
But when method2 worked for a long time (more then 4-5 min) I get exception on JBoss 4 server

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.inactive] [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.inactive] The transaction is not active!
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1379)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:135)
```

and next on WebLogic 10.3

```
Caused By: org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.errorIfClosed(AbstractSessionImpl.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.clear(SessionImpl.java:253)
```

method1 is finished and exception is thrown after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use next constraction at the end.

```
@Stateless
class FirstBean implement IFirstBean
{
   ISecondBean secondBean;

   @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
   void firstPartOfmethod1()
   {
      //...
   }
   @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
   void secondPartOfmethod1()
   {
      //...
   }
}

@Stateless
class SecondBean implement ISecondBean
{
   @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
   void method2()
   {
      //....
   }
}   
@Stateless
class MainBean implement ISecondBean
{
   @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
   void mainMethod()
   {
      firstBean.firstPartOfMethod1();
      secondBean.method2();
      firstBean.secondPartOfMethod1();
      //....
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I would defer any transactional work until all the non-transactional tasks were completed. Easily done by creating a non-transactional 'wrapper' method:

```
class FirstBean implements IFirstBean {
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public void overlordMethod() {
        secondBean.method2();
        method1();
    }
}
```

This prevents the long running method for which no transaction is required from causing issues in the method that needs one. Now, five minutes for a method to complete is ***alot***, but assuming that there is no improvements to be made in the runtime, and that you for some reason cannot reorder your method calls, then you can always increase the transaction timeout for your JTA. Read [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/TransactionTimeout?_sscc=t) for a variety of ways to do this on JBoss 4.

Comment: in this case `method1()` will have `TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED` also

Comment: No, you actually want a transaction active in `method1()`. Using `TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED` causes the method to participate in a transaction if it exists, or start a new one otherwise.

Comment: http://www.javahelp.info/2009/11/01/using-transactionattribute-in-submethods-on-same-ejb3-beans/

Comment: I am *not* recommending you convert `method1` into a non-interface method.

Answer (score 0):

In JBoss 4.x using JTA transactions, the default timeout is 5 minutes.  You are most likely exceeding the timeout for the transaction in progress when "method 1" was invoked because the elapsed time is being incremented while "method 1"'s transaction has been suspended while executing "method 2".  You can confirm this by increasing the timeout to a very large value - [JBoss has a TransactionTimeout attribute that you can annotate "method 1" with](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/TransactionTimeout).

[One non-obvious thing to remember is that when a transaction is suspended, it doesn't mean that the transactional timer is stopped.](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/07/20/transactions.html?page=3)